# Node-REDのデプロイについて

Tags: node.js, bluemix

Bluemix体験ハンズオンの通りにノードのibmiotにdebugをつないで、ケータイのphonesensorから取得したIDを入力したが、右上のデプロイを押しても、「権限がありません」しか出てこないです。
うまく表示できない場合のチェックポイントを参照しても、つなぐことができないです。

私は初心者でまだわからないことが多いので、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

お使いのNode-RED環境はご自分で作成したものでしょうか。
それとも別のアカウントで作成したNode-REDを共有使用されているのでしょうか。
参照権限のみしか与えられていない場合に、そのエラーが発生します。

体験ハンズオンの手順通りにご自分のアカウントでNode-REDを作成し、ユーザーIDとパスワードを指定してログインした場合はフルアクセス権限が付きフローの編集が可能となります。